# Sitecore requires me to login in order to see my website

Tags: sitecore

When I access my site that's being managed by Sitecore, it's redirecting me and asking for Sitecore credentials.  I have no idea why but obviously the main site should be viewable to public without needing creds.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This could be from your sitecore cookie still in page editor mode, To fix this add this query string to your URL:

**?sc_mode=normal**

This will update your cookie and no reddirect to login anymore

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have a combined CM/CD environment and that this is specific to your computer or other authors' computers, it is likely that Sitecore is picking up on the fact that you were using the Page Editor in a previous session.  When you are using Page Editor Sitecore will drop a cookie called website#sc_mode and set it to "edit".  If you return to the page with that cookie set it will push you to the Login Page as it things you are attempting to edit that page.

To resolve this try clearing your cookies or using a browser in Incognito mode/Private Browsing.

If this is happening to other users I would suggest following Martijn's advice in the other Answer and checking your site definition.

Comment: You can also append your querystring with ?sc_mode=normal to force to go into the normal viewing mode. Saves having to clear cookies :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check your site definitions in the `web.config` and/or the `sites.config` in the `/app_config/include/` folder. Most of the times there is some misconfiguration there.

Answer (score 0):

Check the security roles set on your site pages. If for some reason access has been denied to the 'extranet/anonymous' user you won't be able to browse without being authenticated.